# how to re-render all related components with i18n strings once language is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, internationalization, react-hooks

this main App function has a custom hook that will trigger when the button is cliked:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomeScreen from  './Screens/HomeScreen'
import './App.css';
import { useCurrentLang } from './utils/useCurrentLang'
import {strings as engstrings} from './res/lang/eng/strings'

function App() {

  const currentStrings = useCurrentLang(engstrings); 
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
       <div className="grid-container">
        <header className="header">
          <div className="brand">
            <Link to="/" >
                
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="header-side">
            {currentStrings.currentlang.subtitle}
          </div>
          <div className="header-right">
            <button  {...currentStrings}> 
              {currentStrings.currentlang.traduction} 
            </button>
          </div>
          <div>

          </div>
        </header>
        <main className="main">
          <div className="content">
            <Route path="/" exact={true} component={HomeScreen} />
          </div>

        </main>
        <footer className="footer">
          &#169; 2020 
         </footer>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

However this component function that is routed from App also needs to use the same reference of the hook object found in App:

```
import React from 'react';
import terminalImage from '../res/images/GNOMETerminalIcon.png';
import {useCurrentLang} from '../utils/useCurrentLang'
import {strings as engstrings} from '../res/lang/eng/strings'

const { Link } = require("react-router-dom");

function HomeScreen() {
    const currentStrings = useCurrentLang(engstrings); 
    return <div className="home">
        <ul className="menu-list">
            <li>
                <div className="about-link section">
                    <Link to="/about">{currentStrings.currentlang.about}</Link>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div className="projects-link section">
                    <Link to="/about">{currentStrings.currentlang.about}</Link>   
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div className="contacts-link section">
                    <Link to="/about">{currentStrings.currentlang.about}</Link>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div className="suggestions-link section">
                    <Link to="/about">{currentStrings.currentlang.about}</Link>   
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div className="home-main-image">
            <img src={terminalImage} />
        </div>
    </div>
}

export default HomeScreen;
```

Is it possible for both function to rerender when the hook on App is triggered? if yes, how?

Edit: currentLang hook:

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import {strings as frstrings} from '../res/lang/fr/strings'
import {strings as engstrings} from '../res/lang/eng/strings'

export const useCurrentLang = initialState => {
    if(initialState === 0){
        initialState = engstrings
    }
    const [currentlang, setLang] = useState(initialState);
    return {
        currentlang: currentlang,
        onClick: () => {
            if(currentlang === engstrings){
                setLang(frstrings)
            } else {
                setLang(engstrings)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide `useCurrentLang` hook? Where is your `Language Context Provider`?

Comment: @PrãtéékThápá added to main post with edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

The main problem you're facing is one part of your `React Tree` has no idea that the language has changed.

### Solution

Use a `Language Context` which provides the updates to all your React tree and wrap it on the top of the application. In layman terms, now your app is on listening mode whenever `lang` changes. So basically, what React does now is whenever `lang` changes, it will find wherever `lang` is used from the context and update the component.

Docs on React context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

```
import React from 'react'
// import {strings as frstrings} from '../res/lang/fr/strings'
// import {strings as engstrings} from '../res/lang/eng/strings'

const lang = {
  // in this way, you could dynamically add lang
  // later on which worrying about if-elses in your component
  en: {
    hello: 'hello'
  },
  fr: {
    hello: 'bonjour',
  },
}

const langDict = (key) => lang[key]

const LanguageContext = React.createContext(null);

function LanguageProvider({ initialState = 'en', children }) {
  const [lang, setLang] = React.useState(initialState);

  return (
    <LanguageContext.Provider value={[langDict(lang), setLang]}>
      {children}
    </LanguageContext.Provider>
  )
}

function useLanguage() {
  return React.useContext(LanguageContext);
}

export default function AppWrapper() {
  return (
    <LanguageProvider>
        <App />
    </LanguageProvider>
  )
}

function App() {
  const [lang, setLang] = useLanguage();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{lang.hello}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setLang('fr')}>French</button>
      <button onClick={() => setLang('en')}>English</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Question, how do i use the language provider in the App function, since it doesn't seem i can use useLanguage outside of the <LanguageProvider>

Comment: Why do you need to use `useLanguage` outside of your LanguageProvider?

Comment: Because i can't declare objects in the Html field? Sorry it is very late and i am bit confused how can i call my provider in the App function.

Comment: You have to call `useLanguage` from inside the `LanguageProvider`. If you want to call in  App then you have to move your `LanguageProvider` to `index.js` file where you're using `<App />` Then you can do something like `<LanguageProvider><App /></LanguageProvider>`

Comment: ehm it now gave me an error because  `LContext` is null...

Comment: Check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-o6hwkc) out. I've updated the code too.

Comment: Holy crap! it now works like a charm. Thank you so much for your help and your demo. I learned a lot today.